# Is there a way to resize TTThumbsViewController's grid?

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using TTThumbsViewController to display a grid of thumbnails,
very easy. However the hard part is what if I want to display a custom
view at the bottom of the grid? And I don't want the view to be part
of the scrollable grid. How do I resize the thumbnail grid and then
attach my own view to this controller's view? Think of this view as a
custom toolbar kind of thing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a parent ViewController that contains the TTThumbsViewController and your own custom ViewController. If you need to programmatically resize the TTThumbsViewController you can access the actual view through the view property and sets it's frame property.